# Where are the filter image data in this TensorFlow example?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, sample

I'm trying to consume this tutorial by Google to use TensorFlow Estimator to train and recognise images: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn

The data I can see in the tutorial are: **train_data, train_labels, eval_data, eval_labels**:

```
((train_data,train_labels),(eval_data,eval_labels)) = 
tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data();
```

In the convolutional layers, there should be feature filter image data to multiply with the input image data? But **I don't see them in the code**.

As from this guide, the input image data matmul with filter image data to check for low-level features (curves, edges, etc.), so **there should be filter image data too (the right matrix in the image below)?**: https://adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to see? The filters are the weight matrices of the `Conv2d` layers in the code. The first convolutional layer in your tutorial example contains 32 such filters.

Comment: aren't filters predefined, like the butt curve of the mouse above?

Comment: No. The filters are the main things the model learns during the training stage. They are initialised randomly. The fact that early layers generally correspond to edges and colours etc (like the butt curve) is just a wonderful result of the way CNNs learn their layers. The need to learn these things themselves  in order to classify, which is why they do.

Comment: tks, this enlightened me. would you provide a detailed answer, like what are learnt in the first conv layer, 2nd conv layer, etc.?

Comment: Yeah CNNs (and ANNs in general) and what they are able to learn are pretty amazing. Added a bit deeper explanation. You will have to continue your research to delve further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filters are the weight matrices of the `Conv2d` layers used in the model, and are not pre-loaded images like the "butt curve" you gave in the example. If this were the case, we would need to provide the CNN with all possible types of shapes, curves, colours, and hope that any unseen data we feed the model contains this finite sets of images somewhere in them which the model can recognise.

Instead, we allow the CNN to learn the filters it requires to sucessfully classify from the data itself, and hope it can generalise to new data. Through multitudes of iterations and data( which they require a lot of), the model iteratively crafts the best set of filters for it to succesfully classify the images. The random initialisation at the start of training ensures that all filters per layer learn to identify a different feature in the input image.

The fact that earlier layers usually corresponds to colour and edges (like above) is not predefined, but the network has realised that looking for edges in the input is the only way to create context in the rest of the image, and thereby classify (humans do the same initially).

The network uses these primitive filters in earlier layers to generate more complex interpretations in deeper layers. This is the power of distributed learning: representing complex functions through multiple applications of much simpler functions.

Comment: Link to a great paper on visualisation of the various layers of a trained CNN. This will explain it much better than I ever could. https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2901